# how puts function , pointer and string work? why would strchr() get characters after the searched character?

Tags: c, pointers, puts

The example is below. In my understanding, `t` and `p` are the same pointers pointing to the address of a string?
I get confused with pointer and string. Would `puts(p)` give the address of the string instead of characters? Also, I can't figure out how `strchr` funcition works. ++p would point to the next character after ':', that is how it works, is it correct?
 Please help! Thanks.

```
char *t = "MEAS:VOLT:DC?";
char *p;  
p = t;     
puts( p );
while(( p = strchr( p, ':' )) != NULL )
{ puts( ++p )}}
```

Comment: For "what a function does", use the "man" pages... e.g.: man strchr.  Regarding "I get confused with pointer and string":  A pointer is simply a variable that contains an address.  A "string", is not a "formal" type, it is sort of an alias for an "array of characters, followed by a null (0x00) character"... In the case of: char *t = "MEAS:VOLT:DC?"; ... a string is created in memory somewhere, and the address to the first character ("M") is put into the "t" variable.

Answer (score 2):

What is a pointer? A pointer is variable that stores an address (memory
location). This can be the address of another variable

```
int n = 9;
int *ptr = &n; // stores the address of n
```

or it can be the start of a memory block, for example a dynamically allocated
memory block:

```
int *fields = malloc(len * sizeof *fields);
```

Whatever address a pointer is pointing to, we use pointers to directly access
the memory that is stored in the pointer (we also say *where the pointer is
pointing to*).

What are strings? What you've got to understand is that C does not have a string type like other
programming languages do. In C a string is just a sequence of 8-bit values
(representing characters) that end with the `'\0'`-terminating byte. The natural
type for a single character is a `char`, that's why we use `char*` or `char[]`
to get a string.

When you do

```
const char *str = "Hello";
```

`str` points somewhere in memory and it looks like this:

```
b = base address of the first character in the
    sequence

b     b+1   b+2   b+3   b+4   b+5
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

The integer values of character constants like `'H'` are determine by the
[ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) table. So in reality the memory looks like this:

```
b = base address of the first character in the
    sequence

b     b+1   b+2   b+3   b+4   b+5
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 72 | 101 | 108 | 108 | 111 |  0  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So `str` points to that location `b`, `str[0]` is the first character, `str[1]`
is the second, etc. As you see, to get a string, all you need is access to
the first character in the sequence. That's the reason why we use a `char*`
pointer to address strings, because with the `char*` pointer we have access to
the first and the subsequent characters in the string.

A function like `puts(str)` does the following:

- is the current character the `'\0'`-terminating byte?

  - if yes, then exit
  - if no, then print the character and advance to the next one

So `puts(str)` does not print the address where the pointer is pointing, it prints the contents of the memory where the
pointer is pointing to.

A function like `strchr` works like this:

> *man strchr*
>
> ```
> char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strchr()` function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character `c` in the string `s`.

Now that you know about the memory layout of strings, this should be easy to
understand. Let's take a look at this:

```
const char *str = "Hello";
char *f = strchr(str, 'l');
```

Remember, the memory layout for where `str` is pointing to is:

```
b = base address of the first character in the
    sequence

b     b+1   b+2   b+3   b+4   b+5
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
               ^
               ¦
       first occurrence
            of 'l'
```

so what `strchr` returns is a pointer pointing to `b+2` (or `str+2`, because in
my example b is the value that the pointer `str` is storing).

That's why when do you `puts(str)` you get `Hello`, and when you do `puts(f)`
you get `llo`.

A simple implementation for `strchr` is:

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
{
    // stop when the \0-terminating byte is reached
    for(size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if(s[i] == c)
            return &s[i];  // or return s+i; using pointer arithmetic
    }

    return NULL; // c is not found in the string
}
```

So what does this do?

```
while(( p = strchr( p, ':' )) != NULL )
{ 
    puts( ++p )
}
```

The first time that `strchr` returns a value that is not `NULL`, it will return
a pointer to the first occurrence of the colon `:`. `puts(++p)` is equivalent to

```
p = p + 1; // let p point to the next next character after the colon
puts(p);   // prints the string
```

then `strchr` is executed again, because there is one more colon `:` in the
string, it will not return `NULL` but the location of where `:` is stored. The
next time the loop is executed, there are no more colons and `strchr` will
return `NULL`, thus ending the loop. So the output will be:

```
MEAS:VOLT:DC?       // puts( p );
VOLT:DC?            // 1. puts( ++p ); of the loop
DC?                 // 2. puts( ++p ); of the loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation.